# Web audio API: how to play and stop audio?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio, html5-audio

i use web audio API in my game in Chrome. To play the sound, I use web audio API.

I learn it from the article: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

```
window.onload = init;
var context;
var bufferLoader;

function init() {
context = new webkitAudioContext();

bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(
context,
[
'0.mp3',
'2.mp3',
],
finishedLoading
);

bufferLoader.load();
}

function finishedLoading(bufferList) {

var source1 = context.createBufferSource();
var source2 = context.createBufferSource();
source1.buffer = bufferList[0];
source2.buffer = bufferList[1];

source1.connect(context.destination);
source2.connect(context.destination);
source1.noteOn(0);
source2.noteOn(0);
}
```

However, the sounds weren't played. Let alone i want to use **noteOff(0)** to stop them later.

Then i found this article http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/HTML5-audio-and-the-Web-Audio-API-are-BFFs

And i change my code to:

```
    var context = new webkitAudioContext();
    var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    var source; 
    var audio0 = new Audio();   
    audio0.src = '0.mp3';
    audio0.controls = true;
    audio0.autoplay = true;
    audio0.loop = true;
    source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio0);
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);
```

This time it is played!

And here comes my problem: I want to stop the sound with a button.

I tried to change the **audio0.autoplay =false;**

```
      var play0 = false;
      $("#0").click(function(){
    if(play0===false){
    audio0.src = '0.mp3';
    audio0.controls = true;
    audio0.autoplay = true;
    audio0.loop = true;
    source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio0);
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);
    play0=true;}

    if(paly0){
    audio0.autoplay=false;}

    });
```

In stead of getting stop, it is played again every time i click the button.

Two questions:

1. what's the difference between those two playing audio methods?
2. How can i stop the sound manually?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want `audio0.pause()`?

Comment: There is no stop, so just pause it as pimvdb suggests.

Comment: You can combine that - `.pause()` and then `.currentTime = 0;`.

Comment: @pimvdb, can you write some code sample? i don't know much about coding. so...

Comment: Just so you know, `createMediaElementSource` currently only fully works in Chrome. The AnalyzerNode will only get populated with correct data on Chrome, on Safari the data will always empty (or rather, all 0s).

Comment: Most like the reason why your first snippet did not work because you missed out the BufferLoader class:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333777/uncaught-reference-error-bufferloader-is-not-defined

Comment: Well, whats the difference finally ?

Comment: Checkout the library https://github.com/vjai/musquito, it helps to play sounds with html5 audio or web audio easier.

Comment: See answers to similar questions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63501662/9854149

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pause the audio element and set its time to `0`, so that you effectively have "stop" functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5ZuJ/.

```
audio0.pause();
audio0.currentTime = 0;
```