# Playing a simple sound with web audio api

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api

I've been trying to follow the steps in some tutorials for playback of a simple, encoded local wav or mp3 file with the web Audio API using a button. My code is the following (testAudioAPI.js):

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new AudioContext();
var myBuffer;

clickme = document.getElementById('clickme');
clickme.addEventListener('click',clickHandler);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'WoodeBlock_SMan_B.wav', true);

request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

// Decode asynchronously
request.onload = function() {
  context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(theBuffer) {
    myBuffer = theBuffer;
  }, onError);
}
request.send();

function playSound(buffer) {
  var source = context.createBufferSource(), g = context.createGain();
  source.buffer = buffer;
  source.start(0);
  g.gain.value = 0.5;
  source.connect(g);
  g.connect(context.destination);
}

function clickHandler(e) {
    playSound(myBuffer);
}
```

And the HTML file would look like this:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <button id="clickme">Play</button>
        <script src='testAudioAPI.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, no sound is achieved whatsoever. I've tried several snippets but I still can't figure it out. When I try to generate a sound by synthesizing it by creating an oscillator node, I do get sound, but not with buffers from local files. What would be the problem here? Thank you all.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169678/why-certain-wav-files-cannot-be-decoded-in-firefox for a possible explanation

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708513/web-audio-api-no-sound-playing

Answer (score 12):

minimalistic approach to modern ES6.

1. new AudioContext();
2. context.createBufferSource();
3. source.buffer = audioBuffer;
   audioBuffer requests ArrayBuffer data by fetch, and then decodeAudioData decodes to AudioBuffer.
4. source.start()

```html
<button id="start">playSound</button>
```

```js
const audioPlay = async url => {
  const context = new AudioContext();
  const source = context.createBufferSource();
  const audioBuffer = await fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
    .then(ArrayBuffer => context.decodeAudioData(ArrayBuffer));

  source.buffer = audioBuffer;
  source.connect(context.destination);
  source.start();
};

document.querySelector('#start').onclick = () => audioPlay('music/music.mp3');
```

stop play: `source.stop();`

The Web Audio API cannot be played automatically, you need to be triggered by an event.

Creating multiple `AudioContext` objects will cause an error, you should log out and then create them.

[Failed to construct 'AudioContext': number of hardware contexts reached maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046470/failed-to-construct-audiocontext-number-of-hardware-contexts-reached-maximum)

```js
const audioPlay = (() => {
  let context = null;
  return async url => {
    if (context) context.close();
    context = new AudioContext();
    const source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = await fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
      .then(arrayBuffer => context.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer));
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start();
  };
})();

document.querySelector('#start').onclick = () => audioPlay('music/music.mp3');
```

Comment: I originally used the howler library which is incredibly buggy especially on iOS. Switched to using the web audio api directly and no issues on ios, android or windows.

Answer (score 6):

Local files, huh? Are you just grabbing them from the filesystem (e.g. "file://"), or do you have a local web server running?

From what I recall, serving directly from the filesystem violates CORS in most (all?) browsers – which will prevent your AJAX request from succeeding.

Maybe try serving the page with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` or similar, and then access it at http://localhost:8000.

From what I can tell, all of your code looks fine.

Comment: Hi, yes I'm grabbing them from the filesystem. But I will try to serve the page... that would be the only way to make the XMLHttpRequest I gues... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have a call to `onError` which isn't defined.

Apart from that it should be working, but not with Chrome because Chrome blocks all XMLHttpRequest to local files. But with Firefox for example it should work once you define (or get rid of) your call to `onError`.

Comment: There's a nice plugin you can get for Chrome that allows all cross origin calls: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip on local files with Chrome. Do you know any other way of loading a local file with the javascript code? I just removed the call to 'onError' but I'm afraid it still doesn't work on Firefox...

Comment: Then you'd have to check your console, your code looks fine except for the local file on  chrome and onerror not being defined. That said, except if you don't need advanced features, there's an audio element in html that's simpler to use then AudioContext. Here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Comment: Yes, @julien, i'm aware of that. Actually my aim is to do more complex things with web audio than just playing back a file, that's why I'm starting from simple things with the Web Audio API. Thanks again!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @sphanley ok, I've edited, shouldn't have asked the question in the answer I guess, but one problem in the original code was the call to onError that wasn't defined, so it was part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a URL reference to play a local file with two lines of code:

```
const sound = new URL('../assets/sound.mp3', import.meta.url)
new Audio(sound.href).play()
```

The `href` is only needed to satisfy Typescript, otherwise you can omit that suffix.